# Model.find() returnes an object or array of objects? [mongodb]

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

const tours = await Tour.find()

when i use console.log(typeof tours) it shows object in console log.
but when i use console.log(tours) it shows an array of objects.
so i'm bit confused about what it actually returns back?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the value of `typeof` when used on an array is `"object"`. The correct way to check if a variable is an array is `Array.isArray()` - it will return `true` or `false` depending if the argument passed is an array.